# Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be subgroups of a group $G$ such that $AB=BA$ and $A\subseteq C$. Prove that $(C\cap(AB)) =A(B\cap C))$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be subgroups of a group $G$ such that $AB=BA$ and $A\subseteq C$. Prove that $(C\cap(AB)) =A(B\cap C))$.

I'm not quite sure how to approach this.

I have a general idea but I'm not 100% sure on it and it seems too informal.

My idea:

Since $A\subseteq C$, $AB \cap C$ will contain elements of the form $ab=c$ where $c$ is in $C$. But this implies $b$ is in $C$ (not sure about this), hence, we will be counting elements in the intersection $B\cap C$, and then multiplying them by $a$'s which are contained in $A$, giving us the right expression from the left one.

I'm not sure about this because I'm not really using the fact that $A$ and $B$ are abelian. What am I missing?

Comment: You should use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/10513) to make your maths look pretty (basically, put `$...$` around all your maths-stuff, like subgroups, and use `\cap` for intersection and `\subseteq` for ⊆. I've edited it in so you can see what the code should look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $AB=BA$ is not needed. Let $x\in C\cap AB$. Then $x\in C$ and $x=ab, a\in A\subseteq C, b\in B$. Then $b=a^{-1}x\in C\cdot C=C$, so $x\in A(B\cap C)$. Thus $C\cap AB\subseteq A(B\cap C)$. On the other hand if $x\in A(B\cap C)$ then $x\in AB$ and it is in $C(B\cap C)\subseteq C$. So $A(B\cap C)\subseteq AB\cap C$.